# pyto unittest private methods

Tags: python, python-unittest

The class is an example like this:

```
class Tamborine():
    def __init__(self, typeOfDrum):
        self.typeOfDrum = typeOfDrum
    def rumbleTheTamborine(self):
        self.__getSticks(self.typeOfDrum)
        self.__checkTension(self.typeOfDrum)
    def __getSticks(self):
        ...
    def __checkTension(self):
        ...
```

and using the class goes as simple as

```
drum = Tamborin("dunun")
drum.rumbleTheTamborine()
```

but how do I unittest the private methods?  All I read is you should not, but I should, as these are own methods.  So I should also not mock them.  In C, I wrote these test straight into the file where the privates were declared.  How does this work in python??

```
class testTheTamborine(unittest.TestCase):

    test_doIHearSound(self):
        drum = Tamborine("dunun")
        self.asserEquals(drum, "noise")

    test_getCorrectStick(self):
        ?????????????????????????????????????????????????????
```

Comment: *"All I read is you should not"* - you should not. *"but I should"* - nope. Private methods are _implementation details_, test the _behaviour_ of the class through its public method (`rumbleTheTamborine`, in this case).

Answer (score 0):

funny enough, the answer is the same as in C, you need to write the test inside the class defining it as a public method ...

```
class Tamborine():
    def __init__(self, typeOfDrum):
        self.typeOfDrum = typeOfDrum
    def rumbleTheTamborine(self):
        self.__getSticks(self.typeOfDrum)
        self.__checkTension(self.typeOfDrum)
    def __getSticks(self):
        ...
    def __checkTension(self):
        ...
    def unittest_getSticks():
        if_anything_went_wrong = AnyError
        return 0
```

And call the private method tester in your unittest testcase:

```
class testTheTamborine(unittest.TestCase):

test_doIHearSound(self):
    drum = Tamborine("dunun")
    self.asserEquals(drum, "noise")

test_privateMethodStickSelection(self):
    drum = Tamborine("dunun")
    return_value_from_private_select_stick_method = drum.unittest_getSticks()
    assertEquals(return_value_from_private_select_stick_method, 0)
```

BOEM

I am not 100% sure yet on how to write the 'in class' test method and how or what to return, but this is the way forward, at least for me.
Point will be what to do if the private tester method inside the class also uses modules that need to be mocked